# How to fix my table location when export to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

how can i fix location of my table in ssrs to be exported always on the same first row in Excel ? I have also text box above table that is exported or not in excel depends on a parameter in Expression
My table in ssrs looks like :

[image]

For example i want tabel to bee always exported on row number 13 or 14

Answer (score 0):

In my experience getting a report to look good in Excel can be tricky.

I would recommend still showing the textbox that appears above the table, but replace its contents with an empty string.  This way the box is still there and gets factored into the Excel export even if there is no text you want to display.

If you need to push the table down more rows you could also experiment with adding more text boxes that contain empty strings above it.